# Ubuntu 21.04 Dock Bar no more clickable after tablet mode

Tags: 21.04

I have a Lenovo C340-14IML 2-in-1 laptop. After switching to tablet mode and back the dock bar becomes no more clickable until reboot. I cannot click in any app icon on it and on the  launcher icon either.